# PHP Convert From UTC to Local Datetime format

Tags: php

Need a little help.
I'm using PHP.
Here is a example date:
Mon Sep 05 2016 15:30:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)

What i want is display a outpout like this:
2016-09-05 15:30:00

I've tried to convert it using this function:
    date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($time));

But the output is:
1970-01-01 08:00:00

Need some advice
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use DateTime():

```
$time = 'Mon Sep 05 2016 15:30:00 GMT+0800';

$date = new DateTime($time);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$timezone  = -5; //(GMT -5:00) EST (U.S. & Canada) 
echo gmdate("Y-m-j H:i:s", time() + 3600*($timezone+date("I"))); 
?>
```

This doc would help more

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Answer (score 0):

$date=date_create("Mon Sep 05 2016 15:30:00 GMT+0800");

echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");